# Assigning value to a variable not working

Tags: c

I have a variable and a method:

```
char alfabet2[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; 

char is_mixed(char* str) {
    for (int x = 0; str[x] != '\0'; x++)
    {
        if (str[x] >= 'a' && str[x] <= 'z') {
            alfabet2[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        } else if (str[x] >= 'A' && str[x] <= 'Z') {
            alfabet2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        } else if (str[x] >= '0' && str[x] <= '9') {
            alfabet2[] = "0123456789"
            }
    } return alfabet2;
}
```

And I have these errors: [image]

Can someone please help me to make it out?

Comment: You can't assign to an array, only *copy* to it (as any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you). Use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to copy strings.

Comment: The error message is significant. See also the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), and read a recent book on C programming, then the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better C standard, and [this C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: `for(int x = 0; ...` is not allowed in basic C -- C89.

Comment: I also recommend you learn about [the standard C character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: strcpy(alfabet2,alfabet2)  ?

Comment: Also the return type of the `is_mixed` function is a single `char`. Not a string.

Comment: what is `is_mixed` function supposed to compute?

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: `strcpy(alfabet2,alfabet2)` copies `alfabet2` into itself (it's both source and destination).

Comment: Instead of `alfabet2[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`, you probably want to write `strcpy( alfabet2, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" );` Note that you also have a semicolon missing at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the Output, the declaration `int x = 0` inside the `for` loop is not allowed with ANSI C. You will need to use C11 or C99.

Or you declare the integer outside of the `for` loop.

a.E:

```
int x = 0; 
for(x; str[x] != '\0';x++){....
```

Comment: That's only _one_  problem.